# Firebase stop listening onAuthStateChanged

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

As of version ^3.0.0, I'm having a difficult time removing the auth state change listener.

To start the listener per the documentation:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    // handle it
});
```

However, I cannot find anywhere in the documentation that refers to a remove auth state change listener. There is peculiar function on the Firebase.Auth class called `removeAuthTokenListener`. Unfortunately it's not documented ([firebase docs reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/index-all)).

Via your browser's web console.

```
var auth = firebase.auth();
auth.removeAuthTokenListener;
```

prints a function definition that takes one parameter. I tried to do the following:

```
this.authListener = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {...});
firebase.auth().removeAuthTokenListener(this.authListener);
```

but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged), the `onAuthStateChanged()` function returns

> The unsubscribe function for the observer.

So you can just:

```
var unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    // handle it
});
```

And then:

```
unsubscribe();
```

Comment: Oh jeez... not sure how I missed that. Thank you.

Comment: I actually didn't know how it worked, but have some more experience making the most out of our documentation. ;-)

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but why would an application ever need to unsubscribe from this observer?

Comment: For example, when the user intentionally logs out and you don't want execute the listener anymore

Comment: [The documentation for firebase v9](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#onauthstatechanged) shows it works the same way.

Answer (score 5):

This has already been answered really well by Frank van Puffelen, but here is my use case for React components that are getting user data. These components need to unsubscribe when the component is unmounted or there will be a memory leak for each of these components.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  let unsubscribe;
  const getUser = async () => {
    unsubscribe = await firebase.checkUserAuth(user => setUser(user));
  };
  getUser();
  return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```

Comment: not sure why the following didnt work for me. Your answer helped me tho

`useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onStateChanged((user) => console.log(user))
    return unsubscribe()
}, [])`

Comment: as unsubscribe is already a function, you simply need to return that from the useEffect for clean-up.  i.e. "return unsusbscribe;". Much cleaner than returning a function that calls a function !