# Why is there no screenshot in recent apps when finnishing activity in firebase onAuthStateChanged

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I got a very basic splashscreen activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);


    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().removeAuthStateListener(this);
                startActivity(new Intent(StartActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This splash screen opens my `MainActivity`. When I close this activity this is the screenshot in recent apps:

[image]

It seems like it is making a screenshot just too late, which results in this nested recent apps screenshot. This also happen on an actual device. How can I solve this weird behaviour?

Activies manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="activities.StartActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name="activities.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
</activity>
```

The problem seems not the be in the `launchMode`. I keep having the same behaviour. Even when removing the lauchmode.

It has absolutely something to do with the callback. When starting the activity directly, there is no problem.

**EDIT:**

I kind a found a solution. Using a delay in starting the activity resolves it. Although a hardcoded delay isn;t that nice.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        startActivity(new Intent(StartActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
},500);
```

**EDIT 2**

I do not get this behaviour when directly starting the activity. So it probably has something to do with the callback. I'm using google sign-in. It looks like some transparent activity is being closed. Could this be the Google Sign-in Activity?

Comment: Where is the code for making the screenshot?

Comment: There is no code. It is just the default android behaviour

Comment: Have you tried using a real launching screen? I mean using a theme for a custom splash and after authentication setting the content view and real app theme?

Comment: Maybe Firebase code uses this? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#FLAG_SECURE

Comment: I don't think so. The problem only occurs when pressing the back button. Not when pressing the home button.

Comment: onAuthStateChanged will be called either during signIn or signOut so you should use a flag to prevent starting mainactivity during signout right?

Comment: @uguboz yes, my example was to mnimal. I updated my question. Thanks

Comment: can you provide manifest.xml

Comment: @hwd I added the 2 related activities. Would that be enough?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `finish();` you can use the `android:noHistory="true"` in your app manifest like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:noHistory="true" />
```

Or you can use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` in your Intent:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Edit:

Why do you use the `android:launchMode="singleTask"`?
You should probably change this to `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` or remove this line completely.
For more information, [here is a great article about launch modes](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en)

Comment: I keep having the same behaviour. Even when removing the lauchmode.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your problem occur due to using launchMode `singleTask` without `taskAffinity`.

Let's change the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name="activities.StartActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name="activities.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:taskAffinity="your_any_string">
</activity>
```

hope it help!

Comment: I keep having the same behaviour. Even when removing the lauchmode.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce the issue you are describing, but since you say that using `Handler.postDelayed()` helps, try the code below.

By adding/removing the listener between `onResume()/onPause()`, you also avoid starting an activity when your app is in the background. Also, if the `FirebaseAuth` holds a list of listeners, it will keep references to activities that were already destroyed if hits the `onCreate()` method multiple times, for example on rotation. So you can avoid memory leaks.

```
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);

    authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().removeAuthStateListener(this);
                authStateListener = null;
                startActivity(new Intent(StartActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (authStateListener != null) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().removeAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: That too makes no difference. But you were not able to reproduce the issue? I noticed I donlt get this weird behaviour on an emulator with Android O.

Comment: How many times is the listener called? Maybe your issue is due to it being called multiple times? There is a workaround in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/37686371/1449010

Comment: I believe I tested that before and as far as I know it is only called once. It as to do something with the callback. I'm using Google Sign-in for it. Anything You could think of?