# How do I prevent code inside firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged from triggering multiple times in a functional component

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, react-hooks

In my react application, I have a Login/Signup component wherein I'd like to accomplish the following in order:

1. Render disabled input elements.
2. Initialize the firebase auth object
3. After successful initialization, enable the input elements
4. Submit user input to my firebase datastore
5. Send the result of that request to my application's database for further processing.

My component, essentially, looks like this:

```
function SignUpForm() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const handleSubmit = async function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.error('error with logging in: ', error);
      });

    setAuthentication(true)
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(firebaseUser) {
      if (firebaseUser) {
        const myServiceUser = {
          email: firebaseUser.email,
          firebaseUid: firebaseUser.uid,
        }
        postToAppBackend('/signup', { ...myServiceUser })
          .then(result => {
            console.log('result', result);
          });
      } else {
        //do something or nothing
      }
    });
  }, [])

  return (
    <form>
      //...some form stuff with an handleSubmit handler
    </form>
  )
}
```

**Problem**

Because onAuthStateChanged fires multiple times (and as far as I am able to gather, non-deterministically), it triggers a network request each time making redundant posts to my backend.

What I've tried:

Setting state flags in `useEffect` to prevent entering the `if(firebaseUser)` code block if there is a user BUT `myFlag` is false.

Something like...

```
  const [myFlag, setMyFlag] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(firebaseUser) {
      if (firebaseUser && !myFlag) {
        setMyFlag(true)
        const myServiceUser = {
          email: firebaseUser.email,
          firebaseUid: firebaseUser.uid,
        }
        postToAppBackend('/signup', { ...myServiceUser })
          .then(result => {
            console.log('result', result);
          });
      } else {
        //do something or nothing
      }
    });
  }, [])
```

But, myFlag is always false (I think because of the nature of the flag inside the closure?).

I've tried to be exhaustive with my SO research, having found:

[Firebase Android onAuthStateChanged() fire twice after signInWithEmailAndPassword()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674823/firebase-android-onauthstatechanged-fire-twice-after-signinwithemailandpasswor)

And yet, it looks like the firebase docs were updated to reflect this policy of checking for a user before continuing. My code also reflects this. I just don't know how this jives with react functional components/hooks.

**Question**

How, on multiple triggers to the onAuthStateChanged function, do I prevent running the code inside the if block more than once, while using hooks?

Perhaps I'm thinking about this in a non-reacty/hooky way, or misunderstanding how to apply the observer model to a functional react component.

Happy to provide further clarification.

Comment: With my question I'm hoping to come to an understanding how to apply the firebase observer model to the react hook pattern. Whoever downvoted me, I'd be happy to provide more clarification, I'm just not sure what in the question is unclear.

Comment: As you stated it's because the nature of closure of useEffect (you can read more about it here: https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/), you should put `myFlag` on the dependency list. Also you should return a function to unsubscribe to the `onStateChange` event listener to prevent multiple fire.

Comment: I also had a similar issue however adjusted how I handled firebase. My conclusion was that the auth user should be the same across the whole app, hence I created a context. I then used this to register (and unregister) the AuthStateChange listener and pass the firebase user and methods to context consumers. I then put the context provider at the root of my app and now in components I can use the context consumer hook to get the firebase methods and user. With this setup the authStateChange is only run on loading my react app and I can access the methods I need (such as signup) via the context

Comment: Thanks @JamieShepherd, unsubscribing in the effect seemed to do the trick.

Comment: @damjtoh - I haven't had a chance to wire up the context yet, but it's a good idea and I'll give it a shot.