# How can i unsubscribe to onAuthStateChanged

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

previously i was wasting time with `firebase.auth.currentUser` which is giving me `null` when application loads, and i need auth user right when application loads(or a callback will also work for me). then i decide to use `onAuthStateChanged` but now i am unable to unsubscribe it and it is firing again and again, i only want it to give me suth and destroy for ever instantly

So, How can i **unsubscribe** this thing:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
   if (user) {
       // User is signed in.
   }
});
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

frank answered this question here: [Firebase stop listening onAuthStateChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370224/firebase-stop-listening-onauthstatechanged)

> According to the documentation, the onAuthStateChanged() function
>   returns
>
> The unsubscribe function for the observer. So you can just:

```
var unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    if (user) {
       // User is signed in.
    }
});

unsubscribe();//this line will unsubscribe the observable :-)
```

Comment: Thanks! :) This helped me a lot.