# Firebase onAuthStateChanged unsubscribe is not a function error

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-navigation, react-native-firebase

At first install, app run without any issue.

1. check login state at splashscreen.
2. user is not login, navigate to login screen.

But `unsubscribe() is not a function` error show and stuck at splash screen when app is minimized and then re-open. This ONLY happens at the minimize > restore that from fresh install and first run.

Which means if i kill app from background and open then minimize then restore,it works perfectly fine.

Here is the `checkLoginState` function i use from firebase documentation. I not sure this is relate to `react-native` or `firebase` or `react-native-firebase` or `react-navigation`. Any idea how to debug and fix this?

[Handle the sign-in flow manually](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login)

```
function checkLoginState(event) {
  if (event.authResponse) {
    // User is signed-in Facebook.
    var unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(firebaseUser) {
      unsubscribe();
      // Check if we are already signed-in Firebase with the correct user.
      if (!isUserEqual(event.authResponse, firebaseUser)) {
        // Sign in user.
      } else {
        // User is already signed-in Firebase with the correct user.
      }
   });
  } else {
    // User is signed-out of Facebook.
    firebase.auth().signOut();
  }
}
```

UPDATED

In the fresh install > first run > minimize > restore`, app seems like stack or what. If i reload app using react-native reload i got this in log. componentDidmount and unmount run multiple times. Every minimize > restore stack 1. This issue gone if i kill app and re-open. Note this happen in both physical and virtual device.

[image]

Updated 1

This mostly relate to react native. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12562

Comment: I suppose that it happens on Android only, right? Would you test with adding this on your AndroidManifest.xml and see if it fixed? `  <application android:launchMode="singleTask" ....`

Comment: Yes android but not sure about ios. I tried your solution but still same error.

Comment: Try deleting `var unsubscribe =` and remove line 5.

Comment: @MattAft I can't remove unsubcribe because if user click logout button,  onAuthStateChanged triggered then facebook,firebase user will compare at isUserEqual() and log user in immediately. I updated question with firebase documentation link.

Comment: If you set ‘SingleTask’, your app should not restart(should not go to the Splash) when it goes background and come back by pressing app icon. I wanna make sure your app does like that.

Comment: What I'm trying to get at is that `unsubscribe` is not a function, sorry but I don't really understand what you mean or why it's there. You're invoking `unsubscribe` recursively and the only reason you're not getting a max call stack error is because `unsubscribe` is not a function.

Comment: Essentially this is what you're doing (which will give you the same error):
`var test = [1,2,3].map(function (int) {
 test()
});`

Comment: @MattAft unsubscribe is a function that return from `onAuthStateChanged()` also you can call in within `onAuthStateChanged` or outside and it just won't recursively. I know this is so confuse. You can check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370224/firebase-stop-listening-onauthstatechanged or https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login  under `Handle the sign-in flow manually` section

Comment: @BrightLee I already tried 'singleTask' but it just go back to splash screen. If you read my question carefuly. This only happen in first run. Which mean if I kill app and re-open. My app works without any problem. Anyway,  this is properly a react-native bug. I file an issue, you can give it a try if you want to. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17576

Comment: Ah... I got it. then, you can try it with static as a workaround this moment. Maybe you thought that too already.

Answer (score -1):

i also faced this issue and was breaking my head over this...As per the docs calling the listener as a function has to unsubscribe the listener, but it does not. so here is what i did and hopefully helps you too..

```
class Home extends Component {


constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.Homelistener = null;
    this.state = {
          // ...
    };


this.Homelistener = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {

   //do whatever you want here
   // you can unsubscribe from the listener here or do it in 
   //componentwillunmount()

    this.Homelistener = null; // --> just set it to null

  } else {

    //do something

    SplashScreen.hide();

  }
});
```