# How to return true or false from onAuthStateChanged method to variable in separate file

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am attempting to return true or false from the firebase method onAuthStateChanged to a variable in my app.js file whenever the user signs in or out.  I have a class setup to represent the firebase Auth object and a method inside called checkUserStatus() which calls the onAuthStateChanged method as shown below.  I verified that this method is properly verifying whether a user is logged in with the console logs in the checkUserStatus method.  As is it right now, my userStatus variable in app.js is always returns false (even if a user is logged in) and it logs it only one time -- i'm assuming because i'm only calling the checkUserStatus method once in app.js.  I don't know how to structure the code though so I get a true or false value in my app.js variable everytime onAuthStateChanged fires.

```
     Class Auth {

          checkUserStatus(){
            let status = false;
            auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
                if (user){
                    console.log('logged in user:', user.email);
                    status = true;
                } else {
                    console.log('user is logged out');
                }
              });
              return status;
          }
        }

// beginning of app.js
let userStatus;

userStatus = auth.checkUserStatus();
console.log(userStatus);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not how listeners work.  If you need an immediate check to see if a user is signed in, just look at [`auth.currentUser`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#currentuser).  It will give you the currently signed in user, or null if there is none.

The listener/observer callback you would pass to [onAuthStateChanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged) is for responding to changes in the user's sign in status without having to check for it using `auth.currentUser`.  It's not for doing immediate checks as you are using it now.

Comment: Makes sense.  Thank you Doug.

Comment: One important thing about Doug answer is that your code lead to memory leeks, because you is not unsubscribing to the onAuthStateChanged. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370224/firebase-stop-listening-onauthstatechanged