# Is it possible in a Higher Order Component to exclude some wrapped Component from render on HOC render

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-functions, consumer

I am learning React. I have 4 React `Component`s that are Consumer of the same HOC. I would like one of them to not `Consume` the render from the HOC.

Is this possible and if so how to do it? Where to do it, in the Wrapped Component or in the HOC itself?

HOC Provider:

```
render() {
    const { currentUser } = this.props;
    return (
        <AuthUserContext.Provider value={authUser}>
            <Component {...this.props} />
        </AuthUserContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

One of the Consumer:

```
  <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
    {authUser =>
      authUser ? (
        <NavigationAuth authUser={authUser} />
      ) : (
        <NavigationNonAuth />
      )
    }
  </AuthUserContext.Consumer
```

The reason for why I want one Component not to consume the HOC render is because the HOC get initialized in the App.js like this `export default withAuthentication(App)`:

```
const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Navigation />

      <hr />

      <Route exact path={ROUTES.LANDING} component={LandingPage} />
      <Route path={ROUTES.SIGN_UP} component={SignUpPage} />
      <Route path={ROUTES.SIGN_IN} component={SignInPage} />
      <Route
        path={ROUTES.PASSWORD_FORGET}
        component={PasswordForgetPage}
      />
      <Route path={ROUTES.HOME} component={HomePage} />
      <Route path={ROUTES.ACCOUNT} component={AccountPage} />
      <Route path={ROUTES.ADMIN} component={AdminPage} />
    </div>
  </Router>
);

export default withAuthentication(App)
```

And the App.js only renders on start once, right? So it doesn't need an extra render from the HOC, so I want to prevent that.

### Update

Here's a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-firestore-onauthstatechanged-unpgn?file=/src/components/App/index.js:1086-1104) pointing directely to the App.js that have the `withAuthentication(App);` wrapper.

You see that whenever `withAuthentication` Provider render all Consumers fire and that's ok if you need the `value`. But you see in the App.js the `<Navigation />` Component is rendered and it also have a `<AuthUserContext.Consumer>`.

So what happens when `withAuthentication` render is that App.js is also rendered and that is not not needed.

I did some code like this in the `withAuthentication` to make App.js only render once:

```
render() {
    const { currentUser } = this.props;
    let { authUser, once } = this.state;
    // ALl changes to user object will trigger an update
    if (currentUser) authUser = currentUser;
    const renderAuthButton = () => {
        if (once) {
            this.state.once = false;
            return (
                <AuthUserContext.Provider value={authUser}>
                    <Component {...this.props} />
                </AuthUserContext.Provider>
            );
        }
        return (
            <AuthUserContext.Provider value={authUser}>
                <Component />
            </AuthUserContext.Provider>
        );
    };
    return <div>{renderAuthButton()}</div>;
}
```

but I feel that is not a good idea maybe or maybe even a bad idea. Is it OK that App.js render like this since it render the entire app tree?

Comment: Could you put together a code sandbox?  More code would help us to understand the problem.

Comment: You mention a Higher Order Component and four (4) children components, please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example that reflects your question(s)/issue(s). The only way a parent component can prevent a child component from rendering is to conditionally render it. Use memoization techniques in the child component to hint to react that *that* component *may not need* to rerender.

Comment: Thanks I updated with some code and a Sandbox

Comment: You seem to be confused about a lot of things.  My recommendation is that you have **one** Context Provider component that wraps the whole App in order to give access to the current user.  You could still use an HOC to inject props from the context to individual components.  I doubt the user object changes frequently enough for extra re-renders to be a concern.

Comment: Thanks @LindaPaiste took some time to wrap my head around this. I see your point my `withAuthentication` HOC I think is doing what you suggest.??

Comment: I'm confused by why you are calling `this.listener();` in `componentWillUnmount`, but I don't know how the firebase auth setup works so maybe that makes sense.

Comment: @LindaPaiste That is the way to unregister Firestore listener in web version of Firestore - [`this.authListener();`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370224/firebase-stop-listening-onauthstatechanged)

Comment: @LindaPaiste you make a good point about "I doubt the user object changes frequently enough for extra re-renders to be a concern" . I was just trying to be compliant with this talk about making React code streamlined